# How to convert Vec<u8> to typescript bytes?

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-test, anchor-client

In my rust solana smart contact, build with anchor framework, there is one of my variable that is of type in below format

```
struct X {
   a: Vec<u8>
}
```

while building the contract with `anchor build` command in my target/types folder I am getting the type as

```
{
   "name": "countryCodes",
   "docs": [
   "Country code"
   ],
   "type": "bytes"
 },
```

so how can I convert this Vec to bytes in my typescipt test case?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data types from an anchor program via the js types that anchor exports automatically. You can find them next to your output in the target folder after you build and deploy your program.
This is how you can use it:

```
import { IDL, TinyAdventure } from "../idl/tiny_adventure"

export const program = new Program(
  IDL as Idl,
  programId
) as unknown as Program<TinyAdventure>


  const fetchData = async (pda: PublicKey) => {
    console.log("Fetching GameDataAccount state...")

    try {
      const account = await program.account.gameDataAccount.fetch(pda)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(account, null, 2))
      setGameDataAccount(account)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error fetching GameDataAccount state: ${error}`)
    }
  }
```

Like this you will get the Vec-u8 as a Buffer and can then do with it what you like.

If you have the raw data you can also use the Decoder:

```
    const decoded = program.coder.accounts.decode(
      "gameDataAccount",
      accountInfo.data
    )
```

Here is an example using react:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-examples/blob/main/tiny-adventure/app/pages/index.tsx

Comment: what if I have to pass `x: Vec<u8>` to some function argument in rust as `foo(ctx: Context<Foo>, x: Vec<u8>)`

while idl file is showing type = bytes

what to pass in typescript test cases as

await program.methods.foo(
`{
    x: [1, 2, 3]    // how to pass here as Buffer.from() expects string, and [1, 2, 3] are invalid
}`

Comment: You need to put them in a buffer like so: program.methods
      .initialize(Buffer.from([1,2,3]))